# How to set email template in html?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, html-email

I need help to create an Email template. My Email template is in HTML. This template is used to send plain text. My Email template is a HTML table tag.

```
$mail = new email();
$mail->setMailTemplate('emailVerification',array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password,  ));                                              
$mail->sendMail($request->getParameter('email'),sfConfig::get('app_email_verification_subject'));
```

How can I send a HTML email ?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: Could you please try to find on your own ? For example, by [reading the doc](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/04-Emails).

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution:

```
$instance = sfContext::getInstance();
sfProjectConfiguration::getActive()->loadHelpers( array("Partial") );
$message = $istanza->getMailer()->compose();
$message->setTo( $emailDest );
$message->setFrom($sender);
ob_start();
include_partial('templateName', array('data' => $dati, 'title' => $title, 'testo' => $testo));
$html = ob_get_contents();
ob_clean();
$message->setBody($html, 'text/html');
$instance->getMailer()->send($message);
```

Of course, in your global template folder, you'll have to create a file named "_templateName.php" with your email html content.